# Central logs on personal laptop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, dynamic-ip

I got a new laptop and planning to dedicate the current laptop as a central log monitoring system for the server clusters already set up on AWS. AWS servers have static IP, while my personal laptop will be connected to Wifi. The clusters receive low to moderate traffic and there aren't many logs generated.

To use the laptop as a central log monitoring system, I can do one of these things:

- Stream logs in realtime(Using streams to reduce reconnection overheads)
- HTTP Long Polling(Can't push as my ISP doesn't allow me a static IP)
- Make a VPN server and figure out some way to push/poll logs.

I think the 1st option(streaming logs) looks the most promising.
Is there some better way to this?
Also, how do I stream logs in this setup considering clients have static IP while my central server has dynamic IP?
Are there any open-source/existing services that achieves this already(Why re-invent the wheel when you have a start!)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: AWS has multiple log ingestion systems, CloudWatch Logs and AWS Elasticsearch. If the goal is to just be able to look at logs locally on your laptop, you could fluentd -> s3 and then download onto your laptop (or query directly with AWS athena).

Comment: The purpose is to perform intelligence on logs(for eg. ELK stack). That's why needing the logs in realtime.